# Parsley.js Group validation not working

Tags: jquery, parsley.js

i am creating a multi step form and i want to use parsley.js to validate each section separately. i have the following form structure

```
<form role="form" name="stage-1" id="stage-1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" data-parsley-validate>

  <input class="inputClass" type="text" id="name" name="name" data-parsley-group="block-0" placeholder="Please enter the name of the Club" maxlength="100" data-parsley-required="true" >


....
</form>
```

I am trying to validate the form using the following code

```
if($('#stage-1').parsley().validate({group: 'block-0'}){
     alert("Yay you filled in the crap");
}
```

The form is a combination of text inputs and select fields. i have the following parsley.js Version 2.0.6

Any help is appreciated
thanks

Comment: v2.0.6 is very old. Upgrade!

Comment: its on the list of things to do - thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
if($('#stage-1').parsley().validate('block-0'){
     alert("Yay you filled in the crap");
}
```